# Taylor series of Lambert W function $W_{-1}(x)$

Tags: calculus, lambert-w

Is possibile to find the closed form for the Taylor series of Lambert W function $W_{-1}(x)$? What do you think?
On [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Asymptotic_expansions) there is the Taylor series of $ W_0$  around $0$.

Comment: The $W_{-1}$ branch doesn't have a Taylor series around zero since it's not analytic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Antonio said, it's not a Taylor series.  According to [the Maple help page for LambertW](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LambertW&term=LambertW) there's a rather complicated expansion involving log and log log.  Details can be found in [Corless, Gonnet, Hare, Jeffrey and Knuth, "On the Lambert W Function"](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~rcorless/frames/PAPERS/LambertW/LambertW.ps)